# Are the blender adjustable with specified number of lighting sources in the scene?

Tags: lighting

I am design a project include road and I added a lot of lighting sources ( more than 100 objects ) beside the road . When I open material view I found some of lighting source not work ( although I make one lighting source and copy it many times ) . Also I discovered that when I hidden some lighting source the not work group worked normally . Are the blender adjustable with specified number of lighting sources in the scene ?  I'm use Cycles in render option.

Comment: If you are using eevee, there are some limitations to how many lights sources you can use. I think its 128. You can read more about the eevee limitations here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html

Comment: But I am use  Cycles and have the same problem .